# Remove specific string

Tags: r

I would like to remove this character

```
c("
```

I use this

```
df <- gsub("c/(/"", " ", df$text)
```

But I receive this error:

> Error: unexpected string constant in "inliwc <- gsub("c/(/"", ""

What can I do?

Comment: Try : `gsub("c\\(\"", " ", df$text)`

Comment: I don't know what you want exactly, but you use an additional character `"` in your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to escape the round brackets as well as the quotes which can be done as :

```
temp <- 'this is ac(" string'
gsub("c\\(\"", " ", temp)
#OR use single quotes in gsub
#gsub('c\\("', " ", temp)
#[1] "this is a  string"
```

A faster way would be to use `fixed = TRUE`

```
gsub('c("', " ", temp, fixed = TRUE)
```

You can also use `sub` if there is a single occurrence of the pattern in the string.

Answer (score 1):

The opening round bracket is a regex metacharacter; in R, its literal use needs to be escaped using `\\`:

```
text <- "c("
text <- gsub("c\\(", "", text)
```

Answer (score 1):

We can also use `sub`

```
sub('c[()]"', '', temp)
#[1] "this is a string"
```

#### data

```
temp <- 'this is ac(" string'
```